# Selecting an item from a dropdown menu with Selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I'm trying to develop a "bot" to make purchase faster on "zalando" website.
For example, assume I want to buy this: https://www.zalando.it/nike-sportswear-air-force-1-07-lv8-sneakers-basse-whiteblackwolf-grey-ni112o0m9-a11.html

I need a code for select the shoe size from the menu (check the link or the image below), I tried with "Select" funcion:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
 #The first thing you’ll want to do with WebDriver is navigate to a link.
#The normal way to do this is by calling get method:

options = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
userAgent = ua.random
print(userAgent)
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.zalando.it/nike-sportswear-air-force-1-07-lv8-sneakers-basse- 
whiteblackwolf-grey-ni112o0m9-a11.html")

#tried this
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/div[3]')
all_options = element.find_elements_by_tag_name("_7Cm1F9 ka2E9k uMhVZi dgII7d _6yVObe 
pVrzNP")
for option in all_options:
  print("Value is: %s" % option.get_attribute("value"))
  option.click()

#and this:

#select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('id'))
#select.deselect_all()

element = 
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x- 
wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[2]').click
```

But Select doesn't work and I hope someone can explain me why. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This web page has a quite complex structure and does actually not use a `select` element as you seem to expect.

I would always start by having a look at the actual html structure in the Elements tab of the developer console and the size selection looks like this:

[image]

In principle you will have to perform the following 3 steps:

**locate the element that opens the size selection**

This seems to be done with a `button` with the id `picker-trigger` and should work by just using:

```py
buttonElement = driver.find_element_by_id('picker-trigger')
buttonElement.click()
```

**locate the proper size inside the form enclosure of the size table**

The table itself can be identified using the form with name  name `size-picker-form` and the size row by using a span with the specific text:

```py
sizeElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//form[@name="size-picker-form"]//span[text()="40"]')
sizeElement.click()
```

I hope this helps or at least points you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! It works except the size selection...This is the errorr: `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@value='43']"}
`

Comment: @LuigiV. I have simplified the xpath locator and grouped it into one block. If it still does not work it might be related to the timing and you might want to add a `sleep` command before selecting the size or (actually the proper way to go= start using `WebDriverWait `.

Comment: @LuigiV. Did you see the changes in my original answer. Are they working?